# I am using List<Pair<String, String>> but UrlEncodedFormEntity is a deprecated class which uses namevaluepair

Tags: android, http-post

This is my jsonparser class in which i am getting error in params of      httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

```
public class JSONParser {
  static InputStream is = null;
  static JSONObject jObj = null;
  static String json = "";
  public JSONParser() {
  }

  public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,  
  List<Pair<String,String>> params) {

    try {

        if (method == "GET") {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
         }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
      }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

    // return JSON String

    return jObj;
}
}
```

and this is my UrlEncodedFormEntity class which is using name value pair

```
public class UrlEncodedFormEntity extends org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity         
{
   public UrlEncodedFormEntity(java.util.List<? extends 
   org.apache.http.NameValuePair> parameters, java.lang.String encoding) 
   throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException { /* compiled code */ }

   public UrlEncodedFormEntity(java.util.List<? extends 
   org.apache.http.NameValuePair> parameters) throws 
   java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Comment: What error? Clearly explain your problem and what you have tried so far and why it didn't work.

Comment: Pro posting tip: there's no need to add "Hi", "please help me" and "thanks in advance" anywhere in your questions, but especially not in the title, where detail and succinctness is preferred. Hope that helps!

Comment: i am trying to use List<Pair<String,String>> instead of List<NameValuePair> in JSONParser class bute due to UrlEncodedFormEntity class it is giving error in the line  httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params)); which i am not getting how to resolve